# Why to use non-blocking waitpid instead of blocking wait?

Tags: c, sockets, signals, wait

I am reading [https://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Sockets-Networking/dp/0131411551](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551), and there the author handle the `sigchld` in handler that calls `waitpid` rather then `wait`.

> In Figure 5.7, we cannot call wait in a loop, because there is no way to prevent wait from blocking if there are
> running children that have not yet terminated.

The handler is as follows:

```
void sig_chld(int signo)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int stat;

    // while ((pid = wait(&stat)) > 0)
    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
        printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);
    }
}
```

The question is, even if I use the blocking version of `wait` (as is commented out), the child are terminated anyway (which is what I want in order to not have zombies), so why to even bother whether it is in *blocking* way or *non-blocking*?

I assume when it is *non-blocking* way (i.e. with `waitpid`), then I can call the handler multiple times? (when *some* childs are terminated, and *other* are still running). But still I can just block and wait in that handler for *all* child to terminate. So no difference between calling the handler multiple times or just once. Or is there any other reason for *non-blocking* and calling the handler multiple times?

Comment: That while loop condition will run one more time than there are zombie child processes that need to be waited for. So if you use `wait()` instead, it'll potentially block forever if you have another still running child.

Comment: Also shouldn't use `printf()` or other stdio functions in a signal handler. I'm surprised the book made that mistake.

Comment: @Shawn in the book is explicitly mentioned to not use io functions (printf is there just for example). Anyway, you say the handler could run forever (the wait blocks to indeterminity), but that is not true. The `wait()` in loop will run as long as there are childes, but as soon as the childs terminate, they will be `wait`ed and the handler returns. So there is no `forever`. And as mentioned, both version works, so give situation where the simple `wait` would break the program

Comment: Yeah, I just dug out my copy of the book and saw that note in one of  the relevant code snippets. -- And picture a case where one of the child processes is intended to outlive the parent, (or just not exit yet while the parent is expected to do more stuff; if they're talking to each other that will cause a deadlock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop condition will run one more time than there are zombie child processes that need to be waited for. So if you use `wait()` instead of `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` flag, it'll potentially block forever if you have another still running child - as `wait()` only returns early with an `ECHLD` error if there are no child processes at all. A robust generic handler will use `waitpid()` to avoid that.

Picture a case where the parent process starts multiple children to do various things, and periodically sends them instructions about what to do. When the first one exits, using `wait()` in a loop in the `SIGCHLD` handler will cause it to block forever while the other child processes are hanging around waiting for more instructions that they'll never receive.

Or, say, an `inetd` server that listens for network connections and forks off a new process to handle each one. Some services finish quickly, some can run for hours or days. If it uses a signal handler to catch exiting children, it won't be able to do anything else until the long-lived one exits if you use `wait()` in a loop once that handler is triggered by a short-lived service process exiting.

Comment: How could it block *forever* when the parent knows about all its children? And so the children have a point at  which they terminate so once all of the children terminate the wait returns. The only way the children could run "foreever" is in some weird slow system method that blocks. But none of the child call such method. So that argument is insufficient.

Comment: @milanHrabos Why do you think all the child processes will always exit at the same time? Or that the parent can just wait around doing nothing else until they all do?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a second to understand what the problem was, so let me spell it out. As everyone else has pointed out, `wait(2)` may block. `waitpid(2)` will not block if the `WNOHANG` option is specified.

You are correct to say that the *first* call to `wait(2)` should not block since the the signal handler will only be called if a child exited. However, when the signal handler is called there may be several children that may have exited. Signals are delivered asynchronously, and can be consolidated. So, if two children exit at close to the same time, it's possible that the operating system only sends one signal to the parent process. Thus, a loop must be used to iteratively check if more than one child has exited.

Now that we've established that the loop is necessary for checking if multiple children have exited, it is clear that we can't use `wait(2)` since it will block on the second iteration if there is a child that has not exited.

TL;DR The loop is necessary, and hence using `waitpid(2)` is necessary.

Comment: You are right the loop is needed.  But second iteration will not block forever. You can easily do `while(wait(NULL));` and that will exit once all children are waited. E.g. look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669807/whilewaitnull-0-doubts-with-result .

Comment: I didn't say the second call will block _forever_. The second call will simply block if there exists a child that has not exited. Signal handlers should generally not block in this way since this would prevent the signaled thread from continuing execution. In some contexts, `while(wait(NULL));` doesn't work at all, for example, when the child is intended to outlive the parent.